# Integrating Doctrine with PyroCMS

Tags: codeigniter, doctrine, pyrocms

How do I integrate doctrine with PyroCMS?
I have been used doctrine with codeigniter but is not the same thing to integrate with pyrocms.
Can someone help me?

thx

Comment: What do  you mean under integration? I think ORM is the very core of each CMS and it cannot be easily replaced

Answer (score 1):

I can't see any reason why you could not just use Doctrine in the same way as you would with CodeIgniter. Nothing should block that. (Lead Developer of PyroCMS).

Comment: I did it ^^. if someone wanna know how to use doctrine with pyrocms as a helper (autoloaded or not) just read: http://www.estilofacil.com/blog/programacao/frameworks/integrating-pyrocms-and-doctrine-1-2/

Comment: Easiest solution is just to install the Spark: http://getsparks.org/packages/doctrine2/versions/HEAD/show

Answer (score 1):

I did it ^^. if someone wanna know how to use doctrine with pyrocms as a helper (autoloaded or not) just read: http://www.estilofacil.com/blog/programacao/frameworks/integrating-pyrocms-and-doctrine-1-2/